# How to convert image from XML feed?

Tags: xml, image, wordpress, feed, cdn

I am using WordPress with the plugin [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/). I am importing 13 feeds, but with one feed I get an error importing the images of items.

[This is the feed](http://xml.ds1.nl/update/?wi=190309&xid=4006&si=5820&type=xml&encoding=ISO-8859-15&general=false&nospecialchars=true) and this is an error:

> File http://gstar.cordoba.cdn.lukkien.com/publicpreview?sku=20.0.99124.4378.990&imagetype=front&formatID=productImg&commercial_platform=16005933 is not a valid image and cannot be set as featured one

So, the plugin doesn't know how to handle the image URL, since it doesn't end with an image extension (.jpg, .png, .gif, etc).
All the other feeds have images with an image extension..

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to dig the code of the plugin to permit the plugin to use url with no extension?

Comment: No, I haven't. Not sure what to look for, but will give it a try.. Thank you Zekth..

Comment: I think it's one of the simplier option. Or you need to parse your feeds with a php script which save the images without extensions :/

Comment: Might not be that simple for me (not fully a PHP developer, just know some)... but I'll try to figure that one out!